# How linux put SMBIOS information to /dev/mem?

Tags: linux, drivers, dmidecode

I checked the dmidecode source code.

I saw this:

```
int fd=open("/dev/mem", O_RDONLY);
long fp=0xE0000L;
```

It looks like Linux already copy SMBIOS information to memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/dev/mem` provides access to all physical address space. The BIOS firmware is part of this address space (your computer must have some code to run during power-up).

So Linux "did not copy SMBIOS information to memory", `0xe0000` is the base address of the BIOS since ancient times, and reading this via `/dev/mem` will read directly from the ROM (unless the BIOS replaced itself with shadow RAM during the boot process, but again that has nothing to do with Linux).

Comment: Note that in typical kernel configurations, `/dev/mem` no longer provides access to all the physical address space, but only to the BIOS code and data, and any unclaimed PCI space.

Comment: @StephenKitt: Which is really a pity from a hacker's point of view (though it's probably better for security).